# How can I "preview" MySQL transaction changes?

Tags: mysql, transactions, preview

For some database interface I'm developing I could need a preview feature which allows me to simulate a MySQL INSERT query (`START TRANSACTION` ... `ROLLBACK` should do) and see a list of changes. Is there a badly documented MySQL command for that or will I have to - somehow - compare the original with the temporary database via PHP?